# Java: selective synchronization of method based on parameter value

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm writing a java app that send some commands to a set of radios. In some cases, if a certain command is sent to a radio, the app needs to wait for the answer before sending a similar command to the same radio. However the same command can be sent to another radio without causing trouble.

Since each radio is identified by its MAC address, my goal is to synchronize the execution of the command sender method `writeRemoteRegister(MAC,value)` based on the `MAC` value passed to it. Is it possible somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would probably use a [Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html).

Comment: It is, but what have you coded so far?

Comment: Yes. But this isn't typically a use case for the Java Monitor, and on the surface appears somewhat convoluted. You would probably be better of using a state machine, rather than coercing the monitor to suit your purpose.

Comment: This is really hard to achieve, because of race conditions. While you're checking if your message is 'special' (i.e. requires synchronization), the next message for that radio could arrive, and be processed, before the check for specialness completes, thus throwing your scheme out. AFAIK: All the answers provided here suffer from this problem, and it may be intractable unless, in this specific case, you can guarantee this won't happen.

Comment: @EngineerDollery it is not clear from the question whether out-of-order sending of messages would be an issue. All the solutions mentioned serialize the messages successfully, which is all that was asked for AFAICT.

Comment: @wds Yeah, but the OP said that if a special command is received, all subsequent similar commands /must be/ serialized, which isn't possible with partial serialization because of the race condition on the check. A subsequent message could arrive during the check and complete its own check before the first message gained the lock, thus causing out of order delivery. As you say, it may not be a specific issue, so this is a cautionary note rather than an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock` implementation in a `HashMap` keyed by the MAC. Make sure that you also synchronise access to the HashMap, otherwise you'll have a possible race condition when you first encounter the MAC address.

But the Object-Oriented solution is to put the method `writeRemoteRegister` in the MAC class and make it `synchronized`.

Comment: If you assume there's a Mac class, why not use the monitor lock (`synchronized(instance)`).

Comment: The mapped `Locks` worked well, thank you! As for the second solution, `MAC` is actually an instance of `BigInteger`, so I'd rather keep all comm methods gathered in a single class.

Comment: @wds good point. However you would probably still need a Map from MAC to MAC in that case, to make sure that you always use the same instance of the MAC object (you would parse a MAC first, creating a new instance, but you would need the existing instance to synchronize on)

Answer (score 2):

I would use a map of <`MAC`, `Semaphores`> using initial value 1.
The write would `acquire`and `release` respectively in the method.

Here's a link in case you are not familar with them

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/semaphore.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
public void x(String y) {
    if (y == null) { ... Something here }
    else if (y.isEmpty()) { ... something here }
    else if (y.equals("ABC1234)) { 
       synchronized(y) {

       }
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Might be a bit to simple to avoid race conditions.. You need to be synchronized (or otherwise guarded) when you check conditions.

Comment: That won't work. I can pass two different string instances obeying the same equality.

Comment: It's a possible solution @Mike, but I'm guessing it would be hard to accomplish without hard-coding every radio's `MAC`, wich is not a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you can simple synchronized on MAC value. I am assuming you are getting string as MAC value. So you can lock on that string. To make it more safe you can use String .intern.

```
synchronized(String.intern(MAC.toString())){
   // do your stuff
}
```